# Apache2 Segfault - need help interpreting this coredump (suspect cause is memcache / php session related)

Tags: apache-2.2, php, memcache, segmentation-fault

Three Apache2 web servers running a PHP 5.2.3 web site.  We're using Memcache to cache rendered pages but also as the storage engine of the PHP Sessions.

At peak traffic times we're getting Apache segmentation faults on all three web servers and all HTTPD child processes segfault.

My gut tells me that the increased Memcache traffic is stopping PHP sessions from being created or cleaned up and thus the processes die.  Is it possible for someone to confirm that from the following? :

```
#0  _zend_mm_free_int (heap=0x7fb67a075820, p=0x7fb67a011538) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.3.3/Zend/zend_alloc.c:2018
#1  0x00007fb665d02e82 in mmc_buffer_free (request=0x7fb67a011548) at /usr/src/debug/php-pecl-memcache-3.0.4/memcache-3.0.4/memcache_pool.c:50
#2  mmc_request_free (request=0x7fb67a011548) at /usr/src/debug/php-pecl-memcache-3.0.4/memcache-3.0.4/memcache_pool.c:169
#3  0x00007fb665d031ea in mmc_pool_free (pool=0x7fb67a00e458) at /usr/src/debug/php-pecl-memcache-3.0.4/memcache-3.0.4/memcache_pool.c:917
#4  0x00007fb665d0a2f1 in ps_close_memcache (mod_data=0x7fb66d625440) at /usr/src/debug/php-pecl-memcache-3.0.4/memcache-3.0.4/memcache_session.c:185
#5  0x00007fb66d1b0935 in php_session_save_current_state () at /usr/src/debug/php-5.3.3/ext/session/session.c:625
#6  php_session_flush () at /usr/src/debug/php-5.3.3/ext/session/session.c:1517
#7  0x00007fb66d1b0c1b in zm_deactivate_session (type=<value optimized out>, module_number=<value optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.3.3/ext/session/session.c:2171
#8  0x00007fb66d2a719c in module_registry_cleanup (module=<value optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.3.3/Zend/zend_API.c:2150
#9  0x00007fb66d2b1994 in zend_hash_reverse_apply (ht=0x7fb66d629d60, apply_func=0x7fb66d2a7180 <module_registry_cleanup>) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.3.3/Zend/zend_hash.c:755
#10 0x00007fb66d2a5c0d in zend_deactivate_modules () at /usr/src/debug/php-5.3.3/Zend/zend.c:866
#11 0x00007fb66d2541b5 in php_request_shutdown (dummy=<value optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.3.3/main/main.c:1607
#12 0x00007fb66d32e037 in php_apache_request_dtor (r=0x7fb67a229658) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.3.3/sapi/apache2handler/sapi_apache2.c:509
#13 php_handler (r=0x7fb67a229658) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.3.3/sapi/apache2handler/sapi_apache2.c:681
#14 0x00007fb6784166f0 in ap_run_handler (r=0x7fb67a229658) at /usr/src/debug/httpd-2.2.15/server/config.c:158
#15 0x00007fb678419f58 in ap_invoke_handler (r=0x7fb67a229658) at /usr/src/debug/httpd-2.2.15/server/config.c:372
#16 0x00007fb6784254f0 in ap_process_request (r=0x7fb67a229658) at /usr/src/debug/httpd-2.2.15/modules/http/http_request.c:282
#17 0x00007fb678422418 in ap_process_http_connection (c=0x7fb67a2193a8) at /usr/src/debug/httpd-2.2.15/modules/http/http_core.c:190
#18 0x00007fb67841e1b8 in ap_run_process_connection (c=0x7fb67a2193a8) at /usr/src/debug/httpd-2.2.15/server/connection.c:43
#19 0x00007fb678429f4b in child_main (child_num_arg=<value optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/httpd-2.2.15/server/mpm/prefork/prefork.c:662
#20 0x00007fb67842a21a in make_child (s=0x7fb679cd7860, slot=153) at /usr/src/debug/httpd-2.2.15/server/mpm/prefork/prefork.c:758
#21 0x00007fb67842aea4 in perform_idle_server_maintenance (_pconf=<value optimized out>, plog=<value optimized out>, s=<value optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/httpd-2.2.15/server/mpm/prefork/prefork.c:893
#22 ap_mpm_run (_pconf=<value optimized out>, plog=<value optimized out>, s=<value optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/httpd-2.2.15/server/mpm/prefork/prefork.c:1097
#23 0x00007fb678402890 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fff6fecacb8) at /usr/src/debug/httpd-2.2.15/server/main.c:740
```

PHP.INI Follows:

```
[PHP]
engine = On
short_open_tag = On
asp_tags = Off
precision = 14
y2k_compliance = On
output_buffering = 4096
zlib.output_compression = Off
implicit_flush = Off
unserialize_callback_func =
serialize_precision = 100
allow_call_time_pass_reference = Off
safe_mode = Off
safe_mode_gid = Off
safe_mode_include_dir =
safe_mode_exec_dir =
safe_mode_allowed_env_vars = PHP_
safe_mode_protected_env_vars = LD_LIBRARY_PATH
disable_functions =
disable_classes =
expose_php = On
max_execution_time = 30     
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 128M
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
display_errors = Off
display_startup_errors = Off
log_errors = Off
log_errors_max_len = 1024
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
ignore_repeated_source = Off
report_memleaks = On
track_errors = Off
html_errors = Off
variables_order = "GPCS"
request_order = "GP"
register_globals = Off
register_long_arrays = Off
register_argc_argv = Off
auto_globals_jit = On
post_max_size = 8M
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
magic_quotes_runtime = Off
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
auto_prepend_file =
auto_append_file =
default_mimetype = "text/html"
doc_root =
user_dir =
enable_dl = Off
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 2M
allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = Off
default_socket_timeout = 60

[Date]
[filter]
[iconv]
[intl]
[sqlite]
[sqlite3]
[Pcre]
[Pdo]
[Phar]
[Syslog]
define_syslog_variables  = Off

[mail function]
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
mail.add_x_header = On


[SQL]
sql.safe_mode = Off
[ODBC]
odbc.allow_persistent = On
odbc.check_persistent = On
odbc.max_persistent = -1
odbc.max_links = -1
odbc.defaultlrl = 4096
odbc.defaultbinmode = 1


[MySQL]
mysql.allow_persistent = On
mysql.max_persistent = -1
mysql.max_links = -1
mysql.default_port =
mysql.default_socket =
mysql.default_host =
mysql.default_user =
mysql.default_password =
mysql.connect_timeout = 60
mysql.trace_mode = Off
[MySQLi]
mysqli.max_links = -1
mysqli.default_port = 3306
mysqli.default_socket =
mysqli.default_host =
mysqli.default_user =
mysqli.default_pw =
mysqli.reconnect = Off

[PostgresSQL]
pgsql.allow_persistent = On
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off
pgsql.max_persistent = -1
pgsql.max_links = -1
pgsql.ignore_notice = 0
pgsql.log_notice = 0

[Sybase-CT]
sybct.allow_persistent = On
sybct.max_persistent = -1
sybct.max_links = -1
sybct.min_server_severity = 10
sybct.min_client_severity = 10


[bcmath]
bcmath.scale = 0

[browscap]

[Session]
session.save_handler = files
session.save_path = "/var/lib/php/session"
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 1
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.cookie_httponly = 
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.bug_compat_42 = Off
session.bug_compat_warn = Off
session.referer_check =
session.entropy_length = 0
session.entropy_file =
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cache_expire = 180
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.hash_function = 0
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"

[MSSQL]
mssql.allow_persistent = On
mssql.max_persistent = -1
mssql.max_links = -1
mssql.min_error_severity = 10
mssql.min_message_severity = 10
mssql.compatability_mode = Off
mssql.secure_connection = Off

[Assertion]
[COM]
[mbstring]
[gd]
[exif]
[Tidy]
tidy.clean_output = Off

[soap]
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir="/tmp"
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400
```

/etc/php.d/memcached.ini :
    session.save_path="tcp://memcache1:11211?persistent=1&weight=1&timeout=3&retry_interval=15"

Comment: Please, add free/top/ps output before crashing

Comment: @ooshro:  Sadly I'm new to gdb and core dumps.  Does a coredump contain that kind of data or do I need to figure out a way to get the info manually using free, top and ps ? The problem with that is that the crash is sporadic and unpredictable.

Memory and CPU usage never seem to spike too high ... network traffic to the Memcache server does increase however.

Comment: Could you share your php.ini file?

Comment: @Sameer :  I edited the post to include php.ini and then the memcached.ini line that specifies the session handler.

Comment: more likely a software bug in the memcache module

Comment: The problem might be related to some Zend extensions.
I suggest you to disable all cache-related extensions one by one, opcache, apc, anything else, if used.
Also, a list of enabled PHP/Zend modules is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

That core dump only really tells you "I died trying to allocate memory." It doesn't tell you much about why that didn't work out; for that, we need to know about system stats approaching and at the time of the crash. Common bad news we see near this type of error would be a dramatic jump in the number of php interpreter processes, typically because they're not dying, often leading to out-of-memory badness.

I've seen that be the result of system misconfiguration (bad sysctl limits, too-aggressive OOMkiller, etc), and I've seen it be the result of badly-written PHP code (wiating on some external resource that never returns, or getting stuck in a tight loop and running forever).

Can you provide stats on the number of processes and the disposition of your system's physical memory and swap before and during the error condition?

Comment: the opposite - it dies trying to free memory...